# Difficulty with Question 14.6 of Munkres Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:

Let $A$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B$ be the closure of $A$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, continuous function. Give an example where $\int_B f$ exists but $\int_A f$ does not.

This seems to me to be impossible. Since $A\subset B$ and since $f$ on $B$ is discontinuous only on a set of measure zero, then $f$ on $A$ is discontinuous only on a set of measure zero. Since $A$ is bounded, $f$ is integrable on $A$.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Which integral are we talking about? Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: @Thomas, it shouldn't matter since we assume $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: The question is whether the characteristic function of $A$ is integrable.

Comment: We assume $A$ is bounded, so it is, no?

Comment: It seems to me that Munkres Analysis on Manifolds deals exclusively with the Riemann integral (or at least he hasn't yet introduced the Lebesgue integral).

Comment: Since, $A$ and $f$ are bounded, we always have the estimate $\|f\|_1\leq C$

Comment: Take an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}$ of Lebesgue volume $\varepsilon$. I would need to check whether it's characteristic function is Riemann integrable but I doubt it.

Comment: Are we actually meant to assume that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: $f$, but not $\chi_A$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, according to the question as found in the textbook, yes.

Comment: So how could $f$ be "discontinuous on a set of measure zero"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is not the point. The point is whether the integral exists in the sense of the definition.

Comment: Good point. I guess it's discontinuous on the empty set. I was appealing to Lebesque's criterion that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff discontinuous on a set of measure zero.

Comment: @Peter, this seems to directly contradict another of your recent posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560008/difficulty-with-theorem-13-6-of-munkres-analysis-on-manifolds and set $S=B$ in this problem...

Comment: In any case, is there any example of a *continuous, bounded* function on a *bounded, open set* that fails to be integrable?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb Yes I noticed that as I was working through Munkres' text. As far as I can tell I am not missing anything in the textbook.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb there is not necessarily a contradiction to the other question. Not every open set is the interior of a bounded set.

Comment: @Thomas, the theorem applies though: take your given $A$, and call $S$ its closure and assume that $\int_Sf$ exists. Then by the theorem $\int_Af$ exists and is equal to it.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb No it does not apply. My A is not the interior of the closure of $A$. The closure  of on open cover of the rationals is all of $\mathbb{R}$, it's interior is also all of it.

Comment: An open cover of the rationals is not a bounded set.

Comment: I just looked up the corresponding pages in the book. The key to this question is, for sure, the definition of the (improper) integral, which you should include in your question.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb oh please, intersect with $[0,1]$

Comment: Also you seem to be looking into a different edition of the book than the one available to me. In my one question 15.6 looks completely different.  (If I were you I would not waste time on the Riemann integral in higher dimensions or on manifolds unless you are aiming at the history of mathemtics. It's a source of pain, and I still have to see a textbook on the topic which is free of errors and conceptual problems).

Comment: Ah. I meant to type 14.6

Comment: In that case, I don't think it has to do with the improper integral because Munkres hasn't introduced it yet. Then again, it still might. (I would move on from the Riemann integral if I could, but I have to go through Munkres Analysis for my course, and I believe Munkres is entirely Riemann in this book.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting your question by referring to problem 14.6 instead of 15.6 it is clear now (for those who have access to a copy of the book in question) that the definition of integral from the beginning of §13 applies. This reads as follows:

Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Define $f_S: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by the equation $f_S(x) = f(x) $ for $x\in S$, $=0$ otherwise.

Choose a rectangle $Q$ containing $S$. We define the integral of $f$ over $S$ by the equation 
$$\int_S f= \int_Q f_S$$

Now with this definition (and the usual definition of the Riemann integral used on the right hand side) it should be immediately clear that this integral does not exist if you choose $S$ to be an open cover of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ of (Lebesgue) volume less than $1$.

Actually you will find this particular set as an example of a 'bad' open set in § 14 of Munkres' book.

For future questions I would venture to advise that you include relevant definitions in your question, in particular if you have been asked to do so. No offense intended.

Comment: No offense taken.

Comment: So I guess this means even the constant function $f=1$ satisfies the counterexample when you consider $S=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ since the closure of $S$ is just $[0,1]$ so the integral evaluates to $1$ but $f$ is not integrable on $S$ because $S$ is of measure zero, so we can choose any open covering of total volume less than $1$, which implies there exist an uncountable number of discontinuities of $f_S$ on $Q$ (e.g. [0,1]) because there exist an uncountable number of irrational numbers not in $S$ (or else [0,1] would have total volume less than 1). Etc.

Comment: @Peter Yes, in a nutshell. The definition of the integral involves replacing potentially nice functions with potentially awkward functions. Which results in this kind of result. Note that Munkres 'fixes' this shortcoming by introducing the 'extended' integral in §15. The problem with this approach is that if you look at $\int_A f$ the first thing you have to do is to figure out which definition applies to this animal. You may even end up with two possible, reasonable approaches giving _different_ results (like in the example here). Which is why you should stay away from the Riemann integral...

Answer (score 2):

For any bounded function $f$ on a bounded (**EDIT**: measurable) set $A$, set $M=\sup|f|<\infty$ and $|A|<\infty$. Then we have the estimate $$\int_A|f|dx\leq|A|M.$$
Thus I do not see how any such $f$ could exist. This is of course the Lebesgue integral, and since $A$ is open, this is well-defined, and as pointed out in the comments by Thomas, for Riemann integrability you need to be careful about how "bad" $A$ is.

Comment: This estimate relies on the assumption that what you write down is well defined. In case of the Lebesgue integral this is not an issue if $A$ is open, since then it's measurable, but even in that case you need to assume measurability of $A$.